# Phonegap: similar API for IOS for app.loadurl in Android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am porting android phonegap (v1.3) application to ios.  but stuck on following loadUrl api, 
 PhoneGap.exec(null, null, "App", "loadUrl", [url, props]); 
 
I am not able to find out an api similar to this for IOS. 
 
I could use window.location.href, but thats not working properly. :(
 
Is there a similar Api in iOS Phonegap?  pls help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, could you tell me what this code does, so I can try to help.

Comment: um, im not that familiar with iOS actually :(
but this code essentially loads a local html file into the uiwebview of phonegap

Comment: Could you explain more in what cases do you want to load a local HTML file (on start, when you click on a link...)

Comment: um, in my js, when a certain flow of action is performed, then from the js only i want to load this new html file. We can do this using  window.location.href, but thats not loading the page properly.
so i was wondering if thr was any phonegap func api to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following code and they both work fine.

```
window.location="page.html";

window.location.href="page.html";
```

What do you mean by 'not working properly' ?

Comment: ya, this worked in the end. it was not working previously because of something else. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use ChildBrowser plugin for PhoneGap/iOS: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser